# get error when trying to access a file present in other directory

Tags: python, package

Please look at the image below to see the project dir structure. I have a root dir called UI which contains 2 sub dir called test1 and test2. I have a file called C.py in test2 dir that needs a function present in A.py inside teste1.

I get error when I try to access the package as from UI.test1.A import Atest. I have added **init**.py (Empty files) as you can see but I still get module not found error

```
A.py
class Atest:

def printA(self):
    print("A invoked")
```

[image]

I get the same error when running from root
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run it from UI/test2. You should be higher in the arborescence or use complete path

Comment: Do you mean running it from root directory ?

Comment: I tried running it from one level above and also from the top (root) but i still get the same error

Comment: I would say one folder 'up' from UI

Comment: I tried this but I still get No module named 'test_ui'

Comment: try calling from UI:
```
from test1.A import Atest
 ```

Comment: I get no module named test1

Comment: you do have a function named Atest in A.py?

Comment: NO its a class. I have added A's the code in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237319/discussion-between-aude-and-black-sheep-369).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this snippet.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '../')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running your script in subdirectory (~/UI/test2) and import is trying find `UI` module under that directory, i.e. the folder where the script you pass to python is located. The `__main__` entrypoint should always be at the root of your project so you don't mess other imports with having to append to path.

You can see the places where python can find packages with:

```
import sys

print(sys.path)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried running it from root but I get the same error